# pyspark processing a text file

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have a file like this which I have read in PythonRDD.

```
[(u'id1', u'11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|,21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|), (u'id2', u'31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|,41|42|43|44|45|46|47|28|)]
```

**Representation:** the RDD is a pairRDD where each key is a user id(id1, id2) and each value has multiple records (separated by comma) and each record has multiple items (separated by pipe)

I want to reduce the file such that each id: (id1 and id2) will emit as many lines as they have number of record, with user id as the key and some 7th field/5th field , 6th field as the value

```
id1 => 17/15, 16
id1 => 27/25, 26
id3 => 37/35, 36
id4 => 47/45, 46
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (flatMap is the trick):

```
input=[(u'id1', u'11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|,21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|'), (u'id2', u'31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|,41|42|43|44|45|46|47|28|')]
inputRdd=sc.parallelize(input)

def splitAtPipe(value):
  valueParts=value.split('|')
  return (valueParts[6]+"/"+valueParts[4],valueParts[5])

inputRdd.flatMapValues(lambda data: data.split(","))
  .mapValues(splitAtPipe)
  .map(lambda (idx, (data1, data2)): (idx, data1, data2))
  .collect()

# Result
# [(u'id1', u'17/15', u'16'), (u'id1', u'27/25', u'26'), (u'id2', u'37/35', u'36'), (u'id2', u'47/45', u'46')]
```

Comment: thanks so much. I was trying with flatMap but it was not working. I was not aware of flatMapValues. I was checking documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/api/pyspark/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html but it was not mentioned,,, flatMapValues is mentioned in 1.1.0 documentation though

Comment: When I print it, its printed in a file like: (u'id1', u'text', number).... How can I print this in a file without the '(', 'u', and ')'... Since I need this file for ALS algo, I need the output file in a simple format without braces and 'u'

Comment: Use .map to convert the tuple into a string `.map(lambda (idx, (data1,data2)): "{0}:{1},{2}".format(idx,data1,data2))` Python string format tool is very practical too.